# How to clear developer mode?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

I'm messing around with contracts on my own private network with the command:

```
geth --dev console
```

If I want to start from a clean environment (i.e. delete all accounts on the private netowrk), how do I clear the cache?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the directory which contains chaindata and keystore ...
Use the --datadir "path/to/mydir" with geth. To clear just remove this directory.

In short:

```
geth --datadir ~/myprivateblockchain init my_genesis.json
geth --datadir ~/myprivateblockchain account new
geth --dev --datadir ~/myprivateblockchain console
```

To reset:

```
rm -rf ~/myprivateblockchain
```

You could use this python script to create & manage private blockchain: https://github.com/regispietra/CreatePrivateEthereum

Have Fun

Comment: I realized that I could also delete the default data store of ~/Library/Ethereum but keep the keystore.